# I Want To Pass Data From Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

i'm new in android developing
I'm trying to pass data from Activity to Fragment
this data i get from Another Activity

> Activity

```
public class BettingPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    public CardView matchCard;
    ImageView gamebanner;
//    TabLayout tabLayout;
//    ViewPager2 pager2;
//    bettingpage_tabviewer adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private MatchAdapter matchAdapter;
    private ArrayList<MatchModel> gList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_betting_page);


        String gameid = getIntent().getStringExtra(GAME_ID);
        String banner = getIntent().getStringExtra(BANNER);

//        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putString("gameid",gameid);
//        // set Fragmentclass Arguments
//        matchtab fragmentclass = new matchtab();
//        fragmentclass.setArguments(bundle);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Match").child(gameid);

        gamebanner = findViewById(R.id.gamebanner);
//        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.bettingtabs);
//        pager2 = findViewById(R.id.bettingpagetab);

//        getIncomingint();

//        matchCard = findViewById(R.id.matchdetail);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        gList = new ArrayList<>();

        Glide.with(this).load(banner).into(gamebanner);
//
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    MatchModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(MatchModel.class);
                    gList.add( new MatchModel(model.title,model.amt));

                    Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", model.toString());
                }
                LinearLayoutManager im = new LinearLayoutManager((BettingPage.this));
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(im);
                matchAdapter = new MatchAdapter(BettingPage.this,gList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(matchAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

I want to Pass that String gameid which i get from another activity to fragment
"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

> Fragment

```
public class matchtab extends Fragment {

    
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // Redirect to Bet Confirm page
    
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    

    RecyclerView matachrecyclerview;

    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Model> gList;

    
    public matchtab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment matchtab.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static matchtab newInstance(String param1, String param2) {

        matchtab fragment = new matchtab();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
//        Bundle b = getArguments();
//        String gameid = b.getString("gameid");


//        textView.setText(gameid);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_matchtab, container, false);


//        String gameid = this.getArguments().getString("gameid");

        // Recycler View
        matachrecyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.matchrecyclerview);

        gList = new ArrayList<>();
         FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//        DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Match").child(gameid);
        DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Match").child("game1");
        root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    gList.add( new Model(model.title,model.amt));

                    Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", model.toString());
                }
                LinearLayoutManager im = new LinearLayoutManager((getContext()));
                matachrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(im);
                adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),gList);
                matachrecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
        return v;}
        
}
```

Tell me how to send and how to Receive Data from Activity to Fragment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Update your newInstance method and make it to

```
  public static matchtab newInstance(String gameId) {
        matchtab fragment = new matchtab();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("gameId", gameId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Then update your onCreate to

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        gameId = getArguments().getString("gameId");
    }

}
```

Now when you want to create a new matchtab Fragment in your `BettingPage` don't use `new` like this `new matchtab()` but use like this `matchtab.newInstance(gameId)`

This will do the trick.
Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: this give error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: here is my code [Activity](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/esports-f0b71.appspot.com/o/question2.png?alt=media&token=fd19da0d-0ecf-4891-8790-2b8dd5e4fde7) [fragment](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/esports-f0b71.appspot.com/o/question.png?alt=media&token=05a4028f-f554-4ea4-a884-523713a0b73e) [error](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/esports-f0b71.appspot.com/o/error.png?alt=media&token=034c7844-2ae9-4618-bd4c-e73a37471779)

Comment: any solution for this error

Comment: You have to create String variable named `gameid`

Comment: [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/esports-f0b71.appspot.com/o/sol.png?alt=media&token=efdf1769-b0b4-4484-8f6f-e67380e4ee7d) but now my app is crashing when i open this activity

Comment: Buddy you are missing some basic stuff, you you need further help can you please share you full code by github or something

Comment: full code means ? code of Activity and Fragment ?

Comment: Where ever you are getting error

Comment: https://github.com/Bantyyadab167/project/tree/main

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232091/discussion-between-dinkar-kumar-and-phoenix).

Comment: Can we please take this discussion to chat?